# Continuity of norm with respect to another norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm working on the following problem.

> Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ be a normed vector space. Let $\|\cdot\|_2$ be another norm on $X$. Prove that $\|\cdot\|_2$ is continuous with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$ if and only if there is $C>0$ so that $\|x\|_2\leq C\|x\|_1$ for every $x\in X$.

What I've done so far: I am trying to prove the forward direction using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity. For $x\in X$, we want to show that given $\epsilon$ there is $\delta$ so that whenever $y\in X$ is such that $\|x-y\|_1<\delta$ then it follows that $\big|\|x\|_2-\|y\|_2\big|<\epsilon$.

As for the converse direction, I don't know where to begin. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For the first part take $\delta =\frac {\epsilon} C$ and use the fact that $|\|x\|_2-\|y\|_2| \leq \|x-y\|_2$.

Comment: For the second part suppose $\|x\|_2 <1$ for $\|x\|_1 <\delta$. Apply this to $\frac {\delta x} {2\|x\|_1}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you very much for the help on the first part. I'm still a little lost on the second part, though. If $\|x\|_2<1$ for $\|x\|_1<\delta$, I'm can see that $\left\|\delta x/{\|x\|_1}\right\|_2=\frac{\delta}{\|x\|_1}\|x\|_2$; the coefficient $\delta/\|x\|_1$ is greater than $1$ but $\|x\|_2<1$ by assumption. Am I on the right track?

Comment: $\|\frac {\delta x} {2\|x_1\|}\|_1=\frac  {\delta} 2 <\delta$. So $\|\frac {\delta x} {2\|x_1\|}\|_2<1$ This implies that the inequality we want is satisfied with $C=\frac2 {\delta}$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. Thank you!